# Fatal error in Android OCR app

Tags: android, ocr, segmentation-fault

Hi I am getting this error in my android ocr app.
 A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 22846 (a.myapplication).

This is my code

I get error in baseApi.getUTF8Text();

```js
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap resultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.katarzyna.myapplication/files/pic.jpg", options);
        String recognizedText = "cos";
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(AVS_MOST_ACCURATE);
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
     //   Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.lineheight2);
       // Bitmap photo = Bitmap.c
        baseApi.setImage(resultPhoto);
        recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

I tried to change pol.traineddata few times and I used other traineddata files.
I think it is because of the image. Maybe it has bad dimensions? My image height and width are  1224 and 1632.